# What decontamination and quarantine protocols are there for Mars-return craft and astronauts - e.g. The Martian?

Tags: the-martian

Are there any existing or likely decontamination and quarantine protocols are there for Mars-return craft and astronauts?

For example, in The Martian the entire crew have been exposed to materials from the Martian surface, so they could be carrying or suffering from any number of contagious conditions with long incubation periods or subtle effects - prion-type molecules like those suspected to be responsible for CJD/Mad Cow Disease might be lying in the subsoil from Mars' biological past.

Comment: Way to blow the sequel...

Comment: IRL or in the book/movie?

Comment: If you're looking for real life information, this should be migrated to [space exploration](http://space.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This really presupposes the existence of complex organic forms on Mars.

Comment: http://gizmodo.com/5945743/how-nasa-prevents-a-space-plague-outbreak

Comment: NASA already had a procedure in place for the Apollo missions to the Moon, which largely boiled down to rubbing down everything with high-grade disinfectants and keeping the astronauts in quarantine for a few weeks. An up-to-date version of this system would be easy to implement for any potential Mars mission.

Answer (score 3):

In the book, when Mark's little potato green house explodes into Mars atmosphere he thinks the bacteria (or any life form) is dead since the temperature and air is not life supporting. So, there isn't a possiblity that he transports somekind of virus or bacteria from Mars to Earth. Especially not after he performed one-rocket-manned mission when he left the surface of Mars to meet Hermes crew. *But of course, he was so dirty after months of not having a shower they might just be done with it by applying a contamination process for Mark. For his own sake.*

Well, The Martian movie and the book can be applied to RL scenarios except one condition. Andy Weir also mentioned this during an interview. Mars' atmospheric density is not dense enough to create a strong sand storm. So that part is just fiction.

BUT there is also a catch. If you are interested, you can take a look at the [Mars-One](http://www.mars-one.com/about-mars-one) mission page to learn more about a possible Mars mission. They also mention a contamination process for the astronauts. Because you can never know. Some crazy space virus might hold on to you hard enough to arrive Earth.